# My code returns wrong answer, dont know why

Tags: c#, recursion

I'm learning recursion using C# and I wrote this fully working code and I think it should return me 25, but instead of that it returns 5.

Maybe could anyone tell me my mistake?

In my code I have Test class with empty constructor in my main function I create object using that constructor and then I print using Console.WriteLine() where I call `GrazintPitaka()` method. My logic of that method is in code below.

If anyone could tell me how exactly it works, I would be really happy to it.

```
class Test
{
    public int GrazintPitaka(int likutis, int pitakai)
    {
        if(likutis == 0)
            return pitakai;
        pitakai = pitakai + 5;
        likutis--;
        GrazintPitaka(likutis, pitakai);
        return pitakai;
    }

    public Test()
    {

    }
}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        Console.WriteLine(test.GrazintPitaka(5, 0));
    }
```

Comment: why your code should return 25?

Comment: @РахулМаквана Then it wouldn't compile because not all code paths would have a `return`.

Answer (score 6):

You need to do `return GrazintPitaka`:

```
public int GrazintPitaka(int likutis, int pitakai)
{
    if(likutis == 0)
        return pitakai;
    pitakai = pitakai + 5;
    likutis--;
    return GrazintPitaka(likutis, pitakai);
}
```

Comment: It's recursion, the line you corrected is not gonna be used.

Comment: @JustGalgaldas Not sure I follow - I tested code like the above and it worked for me.

Comment: what do you mean? that is going to be used. In your case you are going through recursion, but not returning result correctly. You return the result of the first iteration, see? you need to return the result of each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

In your `GrazintPitaka` method these lines:

```
    likutis--;
    GrazintPitaka(likutis, pitakai);
```

are pretty useless as it does not affect the result. Perhaps you wanted to assign return value of `GrazintPitaka(likutis, pitakai)` and use it, but you did not do that, therefore as `0 + 5` is `5`, your code works as expected.

```
   if(likutis == 0)
        return pitakai;
```

Not using `{}`  for one-liners in languages using preprocessor is like asking for troubles for more serious projects.

Answer (score 1):

Each `pitakai` and `likutis` in each depth of your function is *different*. The returned value *does not* change the value of `pitakai` in outer level of function. That’s why you cannot get desired result.

To get desired result, you have to write

```
pitakai = GrazintPitaka(likutis, pitakai);
```

so that it gets updated for every depth.